# Changes made to UI objects are not updating in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to objective-c and iPhone, but have done lots of java coding in past.
Tearing hair out about v. basic things which I'm usually eventually able to find answer to, but not this one!

I'm wanting to make a label's background colour change, code below.  No matter what I do it doesn't change when I run it on the iPhone simulator.  Is there some setting there, I feel like I'm asking a very stupid question but really can't find an answer.  Is this a problem with the setup of the development environment??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"setting label to black color");
    self.colourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: Try Project > Clean, and then iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

Comment: What's `self.colourLabel`? An outlet?

Comment: Make sure IBOutlet to UILabel is set in Interface Builder. Sometimes connections get broke without any Apparent reason. (though there always is some).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make an IBOutlet of type UILabel, hook it up to the label in the interface builder and do:

> yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whateverColor];

Did you set `colorLabel` as a property? Because you wouldn't need to... unless you have two separate classes that you want to communicate with each other.

Comment: Thank you.  I was using a IBOutlet type of UILabel, and I had synthesised it, however I had forgotten to hook up the label I had drawn with what I had put in code. Both learning objective-c and also the rather unintuitive interface builder at the same time is a bit confusing.  Anyway thank you very much for your quick responses, this is a great community!

Comment: Glad I could help. Objective-C is a bit confusing when you first get started, but you'll get used to it. Make sure to up vote if it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Just tried, but it says that I require more reputation before being allowed to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in Objective-C sending messages to `nil` objects is fine, so the problem may be that `self.coulourLabel` is still `nil` at that time.

How and where do you instantiate it? Did you set the `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd leave an answer emphasising the suggestion from @Dima in the comments on the question - ie, Project > Clean and then iOS Simulator > Reset Content And Settings.

I just solved a similar problem which was occurring with a UIButton created in code, and so couldn't have been an IBOutlet issue. Changes I made to the code (even deleting the property altogether) weren't showing up when I ran in the simulator, even though on my device it worked fine. I had assumed that doing a clean would be enough but it wasn't until I did the Reset Content And Settings that it started behaving as I expected.

Hope someone finds this useful...